# Excel: How to create a list of all values in a column that fall between two other values provided

Tags: arrays, excel, list, between

Just wondering if someone can help me with a formula.

In column A, I have a list of incremental values (complex decimals).

I would like to create a list in column D of all values in column A that fall between a lower and upper value in column B and C.

Thanks!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iC79.png)

Comment: Just use a filter.  To put your results in a separate column, use the `Advanced Filter`. See Help or search the internet for instructions, and post back with any issues you may have.  This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your idea Ron Rosenfeld. Unfortunately, I need a formula as it needs to be dynamic. The formula will be repeated 30 times or so on the one page using the same list but different upper and lower values. The upper and lower limits are derived from formulas on another worksheet and the resulting list is then used to perform more formula based calculations on a third worksheet. I'm fairly good with formulas but this one has me stumped so I've come to the place that I get all of the best advice from...

Comment: There are answers out there if you search for something like 'Excel list unique values with a condition'

Answer (score 0):

There is a brilliant solution for this in http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/10/04/formula-forensics-no-030/

I use it a lot and I modified the formula based on your image.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$25, MATCH(MIN(MODE.MULT(IF(($A$2:$A$25>$B$2)*($A$2:$A$25<$C$2)*NOT(COUNTIF($D$1:$D1, $A$2:$A$25)), (COUNTIF($A$2:$A$25, "<"&$A$2:$A$25)+1)*{1,1}))), IF(Criteria,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$25, "<"&$A$2:$A$25)+{1}), 0)), "")
```

Put the formula in D2 and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter as it is an array formula. Then copy it down.

If you want numbers that are equal to the cells in B2, C2 to be included, modify the ">B2" to ">=B2" and similarly for C2.